# Commafication of a number using vim regex

Tags: regex, vim, vi, regex-lookarounds

While reading the book "**Mastering regular expression**", I tried to solve the problem of "commafication" of a number using the vim editor.

How is it possible to turn a number in a file from:

> 1234567891234

to

> 1,234,567,891,234

(this is what is called by commafication of a number)

there is a solution using the **lookaround** but I tried to solve it without using that. Unfortunately I still not come up with the right command and that's why I am here.
Here is my command till now:

```
:%s/\(\d\)\(\(\d\d\d\)\+\)/\1,\2/gc
```

which produces:

> 1,234567891234

The problem is with `\+` which takes the longest chain. How can I repeat that for the rest of the chain?

Answer (score 3):

In `vim` you can use this regex to insert comma after every 3 digits:

```
:%s/\v(^)@!((\d{3})+$)@=/,/g
```

This is assuming each number is on a separate line.

If you have more than one number per line then use:

```
:%s/\v(<)@!((\d{3})+>)@=/,/g
```

[Here is RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fC2eD6/1)

PS: Tested on `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2` and `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4`

Comment: is there a solution without using @= @! @<= @<! ?

Comment: Look around is indeed needed to solve this problem since we need to see if there are 3 digits ahead before inserting a comma

Comment: I am totally aware of that but do you mean it is impossible to solve it without lookaround ( Note: your command needs some correction to work well in vi )

Comment: I posted it after testing it myself in `vim`. And no I'm not aware of any regex without look-arounds to solve this.

Comment: then sorry, which version are you using please ?

Comment: yeah okay you are using the \v great I did not know that ! :) thx

Comment: Yes that is for turning on `very magic` and avoiding excessive escaping. I've edited my answer as well.

Comment: I have already this solution but it doesn't answer my question. I cannot approve it!